# Cannot upload debug files to Sentry

Tags: ios, xcode, sentry, dsym

So, we are currently trying to upload debug files to Sentry using GitHub Actions after a `xcodebuild test` command:

```
set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild test -scheme Myscheme -workspace myworkspace.xcworkspace -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=17.0.1,name=iPhone 15 Pro' -enableCodeCoverage YES -allowProvisioningUpdates CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO | xcpretty
```

For this, we use the following sentry cli command:

```
sentry-cli debug-files upload --auth-token ${{ secrets.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN }} \
--include-sources \   
--org myorg \   
--project myproject \   
$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME
```

But this command gives us an `Permission denied (os error 13)`. Trying to change permissions in directory doesn't worked either.

And we can´t upload the debug files in the build phases because we can´t expose our Sentry token.

Some extra information: our workflow in GitHub Actions is running on macos-13.

Any ideas that could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your dSYMs should be in the DerivedData folder on GH actions. Try running

```yaml
sentry-cli debug-files upload --auth-token ${{ secrets.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN }} \
--include-sources \   
--org myorg \   
--project myproject \   
DerivedData/
```

The `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` and `DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME` are specific to Xcode. I wouldn't expect them to work in GH Actions. If `DerivedData/` doesn't work, you can get their values by using the `-showBuildSettings` `xcodebuild` flag.

You can also specify a custom derived data location by using the `-derivedDataPath` option of xcodebuild.

Comment: So I tried this using the exact same value that appears in DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH when using -showBuildSettings. But now it just prints this: > Found 0 debug information files > No debug information files found
Which doesn't make any sense.